# Specifying @CrossOrigin orgins via an environment variable

Tags: java, spring, cors, environment-variables, spring-annotations

Is it possible to specify the origins for the `@CrossOrigin` Annotation via an environment variable? I want to do this so that I can use the same code base for uat/staging/production. I want my uat/staging environments to be accessible via localhost for testing, but my production environments to only accept requests from one specific endpoint.

For example this is our cross origin annotation user for a new API;

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:9000", "http://example.com"})
```

This works fine. Testing on my local machine, only a webserver running on port 9000 could access my API. I then tried setting my environment variable on my local windows machine

```
ALLOWED_ORIGINS = http://localhost:9000,http://example.com
```

I then changed the annotation too

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "#{'${allowed.origins}'.split(',')}")
```

And now the requests are blocked due to CORS.

As a follow up question. Can I set the port as a wildcard? So that any localhost webserver can access the API?

**UPDATE**

So I was able to achieve the first part of my question via - https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support

and setting the env variable for `allowedOrigins()`

```
@Value("#{'${allowed.origins}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> allowedOrigins;
```

However for the life of me I can't seem to get any form of wildcard/pattern matching working. I have tried both of the below as environment variables;

```
http://localhost:*
http:\/\/localhost:[0-9]+
```

I may have to raise this as a seperate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, Annotations are processed at compile time only. 
You can't process or provice dynamic data.
The configuration data has to be fixed or constant.

If you are making use of xml to configure spring. You can configure spring using following code.

```
<mvc:cors>

    <mvc:mapping path="/api/**"
        allowed-origins="http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com"
        allowed-methods="GET, PUT"
        allowed-headers="header1, header2, header3"
        exposed-headers="header1, header2" allow-credentials="false"
        max-age="123" />

    <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**"
        allowed-origins="http://domain1.com" />

</mvc:cors>
```

Source [link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

It you need any further configuration, you will have to provide your own filter for CORS processing, then, simply replace your CORS filter in filter chain.

Comment: I will not be using xml based configuration. I also need pattern matching to allow all localhost ports so it looks like I will have to use the CORS Filter if I'm understanding things correctly.

Comment: Are you using Java based configuration ?

Comment: Yes I am. - https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support is how I got it working.