# How to get Application properties configuration into Annotation as parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-annotations

I want to use **@CrossOrigin** annotation on my **RestController** in my Spring Boot application and set **origins** parameter with the values from **application.properties** file.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${app.cors.origins}"})
public class SomeController(){
//
//
}
```

I set the property in my application.properties file like

```
app.cors.origins =http://www.google.com,http://localhost:8001
```

However that doesn't work as a cross origin request from http://localhost:8001 to my app fails with CORS error on the browser.

Am I missing something on setting the property?

**Update :** Problem is to set origins as a string array from the value of application  property entry. When I hardcode the urls in origin, it works.

Thanks

Comment: Actually problem is to set `origins` parameter of `@CrossOrigin` annotation, when I hardcode the url into origins it works. 

Problem is to create an string array from application property in annotation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `application.properties` to set origins of CORS then this is the solution.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${app.cors.origins}")
    private String corsAllowedOrigins;

    @Value("${app.cors.methods}")
    private String corsAllowedMethods;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(corsAllowedOrigins)
                .allowedMethods(corsAllowedMethods);

    }
```

***application.properties***

```java
app.cors.origins=http://www.google.com,http://localhost:8001
app.cors.methods=GET,OPTIONS
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, our requirement is to use cors on controller level, not globally. so I can't use configurations, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to use environment variables on @CrossOrigin annotation because annotations are processed at compile time only.  You can read more on this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974133/specifying-crossorigin-orgins-via-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on this issue, I found another post mentioned about controller level parameter annotation for Cors. I haven't try it yet. share it with you:

Create your custom annotation and annotate the API with that.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@CrossOrigin
public @interface CrossOriginsList {

    public String[] crossOrigins() default  {

            "http://domain1.com", "http://domain1.com"
            "http://domain1.com", "http://domain1.com"
            // Pass as many as you want
    };
}
```

And now Annotate your API with this custom Annotation

```
@CrossOriginsList
    public String methodName() throws Exception
{
        //Business Logic
}
```

Comment: Does this approach allow me to define crossorigins values dynamically? It seems it's populated statically again.